# passing parameter in Rest API request from other file or list variable- using

Tags: python, rest, marketo

new to python and API.
i have  list of values like below
typeid=['1','12','32','1000','9']

I have to pass this  value as parameter in API request, so that it would take one typeid at a time and  append the json.  code i have following but not sure how it will move from one value to other?

```
# activity type id store as following in other .py file typeid=['1','12','32','1000','9']

#importing the file in main program file.

From typeid list import activitytypeids 


act1 = requests.get(host + '/rest/v1/activities.json',
                    params={
                            'activityTypeIds': activitytypeids[0]
                            }).text

json_obj = json.loads(act1)
results.append(json_obj)
more_result = json_obj['moreResult']
while True:
    act1 = requests.get(host + '/rest/v1/activities.json',
                        params={
                                'activityTypeIds': activitytypeids[0]
                                }).text
    json_obj = json.loads(act1)
    results.append(json_obj)
    more_result =json(results['moreResult'])

    if not more_result:
        break
```

How do I pass the activity's in request param one by one, so that get the result of all type ids.

Comment: `for activity_id in ids_list: get_activity_id(activity_id)` ...

Comment: wait you set the value named `activityTypeIds` and it only takes one? that seems like the API should be able to accept more than 1....

Comment: parameter do take more than one , but we are trying to pass one id so that it doesn't overwhelmed the system. as data volume is high.

Answer (score 0):

take your code to get one id and put it in a function that accepts an `activity_id`, and change all `activitytypeids[0]` to just be `activity_id`

From typeid list import activitytypeids

```
def get_activity_id(activity_id):
    act1 = requests.get(host + '/rest/v1/activities.json',
                    params={
                            'activityTypeIds': activity_id
                            }).text
    return act1.json()
```

then you can just iterate over your list

```
results = [get_activity_id(id) for id in activitytypeids]
```

that said it seems very surprising that a variable named `activityTypeIds` only accepts one id ... i would very much expect this to be able to accept a list based on nothing more than the variable name